# Find node voltages for MOSFETs given Vdd

Tags: voltage, mosfet

In this circuit, Vdd = 5V. We are given the channel widths to be 11.1 um, 25 um, and .25 mm for M1, M2, M3 respectively.

The hint is to use an iterative process, so from what I understand we have to make initial assumptions. I know that all MOSFETs are in saturation because \$V_{DS} > V_{OV} \$.

I am not sure what other assumption to make.

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Comment: It means you assume each MOSFETs has a particular mode of operation and assign it voltages values accordingly then solve for everything. Then you check again to see if if your result contradicts or supports those initial assumptions.

Comment: I understand every MOSFET is in saturation. But I do not know what else to assume